# use ajax argument to send argument to flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so I used some Javascript to send a post request to a flask route. However, I do struggle with also sending an argument to the function. This is my approach (just a short excerpt):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/longtask',
    data {
    bigID = '0';
}
});
```

Unfortunately, the longtask function doesn't receive the bigID.
Can you guys please help me?

Cheers and thank you!

Comment: You have a syntax error.  kv pairs in javascript objects are represented with a colon (`:`) not an equals sign (`=`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/longtask',
    data: {
        bigID : '0'
    }
});
```

You can try again with the above code.